# Redux-saga store config error with combineReducer

Tags: redux, redux-saga, reducers

I try to config my saga store with Redux-saga, but I keep getting error about 
`Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.`

I did google around check the documentation, adjust my code still have the issue, so hoping someone can point out for me. Thanks!

if I change this code 
`const sagaMiddleware = ReduxSaga.default();`
to
`const sagaMiddleware =()=> ReduxSaga.default();`
I got other error about: `sagaMiddleware.run is not a function`

**Main.js**

```
const { createStore, applyMiddleware } = require("redux");
const { createSelector } = require("reselect");
const ReduxSaga = require("redux-saga");
const createSagaMiddleware = require("redux-saga");
const reducer = require("./reducers/index");
const { workerSaga } = require("./sagas/sampleSaga.js");

const sagaMiddleware = ReduxSaga.default();
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));

sagaMiddleware.run(workerSaga);
```

**Reducers/index.js**

```
const { combineReducers } = require("redux");
const sample1 = require("./sample1");
const sample2 = require("./sample2");
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  sample1,
  sample2
});
module.exports = rootReducer;
```

**Reducers/sample1.js**

```
const {
  STARTS_LOADING_SAMPLE,
  FETCH_SAMPLE,
  COMPLETE_FETCHING_SAMPLE
} = require("../actions/index");

const sampleInitialState = {
  fetching: false,
  complete: false,
  sample1: []
};
//switch statement....

module.exports = {
  sample1: (allReducer, sampleInitialState)
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reducer is a pure function that takes the previous state and an action, and returns the next state. But you are exporting an object instead of a function in `Reducers/sample1.js` file. Try changing it to something like this:

```
...
module.exports = function(state = sampleInitialState, action) {
   // switch statements
};
```

More on reducers: https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers

Comment: Hi Mezba, I updated reducer module export to be function, but in my `reducers/index.js` combineReducer need object, because right now I log my state will display: `state { sample1: [Function] }`, how can I fix that to be object in combineReducer? Thanks!

Comment: `combineReducers` takes an object whose values are different reducing functions. So `state { sample1: [Function] }` is the correct behavior, it must be a `function` and not an `object`. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. @madebymt